# Is there a way to offset concatenations manually and/or add connecting lines to concatenated charts in Altair?

Tags: altair

I have the following concatenated chart:
[image]

The code used to generate it is as follows:

```
def quarterly_avg_bar_graph(city):
    data = climate_with_seasons[climate_with_seasons['city'] == city]
    grouped = data.groupby('season')[['sunshine']].mean().reset_index()
    
    chart = alt.Chart(grouped).mark_bar().encode(
        alt.X('season:N', sort=['spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter']),
        alt.Y('sunshine:Q'),
        alt.Color('season:N', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='pastel1'), sort=['spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter'], legend=None)
    ).properties(
        height=75,
        width=75
    )
    
    return chart

seattle = quarterly_avg_bar_graph('Seattle')
chicago = quarterly_avg_bar_graph('Chicago')
sf = quarterly_avg_bar_graph('San Francisco')
houston = quarterly_avg_bar_graph('Houston')
miami = quarterly_avg_bar_graph('Miami')
ny = quarterly_avg_bar_graph('New York')

background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
        fill='white',
        stroke='lightgray'
    ).properties(
        width=300,
        height=300
    ).project('albersUsa')

# Generate the points themselves
climate_points = alt.Chart(climate).mark_square(color='red').encode(
    alt.Longitude('lon:Q'),
    alt.Latitude('lat:Q'),
    alt.OpacityValue(0.05),
)

text = climate_points.mark_text(
        dx=15,
        dy=10
    ).encode(
        text='city:N'
    )

map_chart = background + climate_points + text
left = seattle & sf
right = ny & miami
middle = alt.vconcat(alt.vconcat(chicago, map_chart, center=True), houston, center=True)
final_chart = alt.hconcat(left, middle, right, center=True)
final_chart.configure_square(size=150)
```

I would like to make the connections between geographic location and bar graph a little more clear (move the top bar graph a little to the right, the right bottom one down a little, etc.), as well as add a line connecting each city square mark to its respective bar graph. Can this be done natively in Altair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the spacing between concatenated objects with the `spacing` parameter:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

points = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color='Origin:N'
)

bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    y='Origin:N',
    color='Origin:N',
    x='count(Origin):Q'
)

alt.vconcat(points, bars, spacing=200)
```

[image]

I don't think that you can add an annotation that spans the space between the graphs unfortunately. You can add a line that goes outside the grid [by using `clip` and limiting the domain as in the documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html?highlight=clip#adjusting-axis-limits), but it would not span the spacing between the charts (you could possibly use this line to push the charts apart instead of the spacing, but it will require a lot of fiddling I am afraid).